# Looping through dataframe to search for substring and change column on a big table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I got two data frames and I want to change the column of one dataframe based on the column of the other dataframe.

```
 df1
                              A              label
0  2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X           0
1  2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX           0
2  2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X        0
3  2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324             0
4  2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X            0

df2
         Id          Label
0  BID_-324          Y
1  BID_123           Y
2  BID_-398          N
```

What I want to do is,  I want to change the label of the df1 dataframe depending on the 'BID*' substring contained in it. The new label should be based on the label of the 'BID*' in df2.

My code is given below.  But it takes more than 12 hours (still did not finish) to run.  My dataframes got more than 1 million entries.

```
df3 = df2[df2.Label == 'Y']
for ind, row in df3.iterrows():
    idx = df1[df1.A.str.contains(row['Id'])].index
    df1.loc[idx,'label'] = 1
```

Any help ?

Comment: Can you post the desired output as a dataframe so we know what you are taking please.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.extract` with `replace`:

```
s = df2.set_index("Id")["Label"]
df["label"] = df["A"].str.extract("(%s)" % "|".join(s.index)).replace(s)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                        A label
0     2018 43 NFO BID_-324 dfs.DataNode X     Y
1     2018 5  NFO dfs.FSNames BID_123  XX     Y
2  2019 13 NFO BID_-398 dfs.DataNode  X X     N
3       2019 45 NFO dfs.DataNode BID_-324     Y
4      2019 14 NFO BID_123 dfs.DataNode X     Y
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is join all values join by `|` and pass to `str.contains`:

```
s = df2.loc[df2.Label == 'Y', 'Id']
df1.loc[df1.A.str.contains('|'.join(s)), 'label'] = 1
```